# How can I get Chrome to open one process per tab?

Tags: google-chrome, freebsd, tabs, multi-threaded

I am on amd64 FreeBSD 11.0-p9 using Chromium 57.0.2987.133 precompiled from the ports. Version 58 causes graphical glitches on my system so I haven't upgraded yet.

Since about half a year I encounter a problem where randomly, some tabs randomly get “stuck,” as in, the tab icon is a spinner and the tab does not react to inputs or hotkeys. I cannot even close the tab by clicking on the <kbd>×</kbd> button. Some times, the tab closes with great delay after I clicked <kbd>×</kbd> but most of the time it doesn't. Usually, only opening a new tab, pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd> to open the task manager and then closing the offending tab group solves the problem.

Part of why this problem is so annoying is that all tabs in a process are affected. So if I have 10 reddit tab open and one of them gets stuck, I have to force-close all 10 tabs.

Is there a way to make Chrome use a separate thread/process for each tab so one tab getting stuck does not affect the others?